# Teamcity nugets with .net 5.0 not showing up in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019, teamcity

I am building an assembly based on .NET 5.0, and I am publishing it as a nuget package, to be used in other projects.

It is built with Teamcity on premises, and published here, too:

[image]

When I try to use it in another solution in Visual Studio, it doesn't show up in the list of nuget packagess. Yes, the assembly/nuget is there, but not in the correct version:

[image]

I just upgraded the target framework in the devexpress build jobs to be net5.0windows7.0

[image]

I am wondering if that has caused my trouble or it may basically be that .net5.0 is no longer supported...

(I intended to do that upgrade as next step, but I don't want to leaves something broken).

Has anyone had the same experience of nuget packages not being shown?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, found it ;-)
just had to look in the right place...
[image]

It is simply the sort order, and the change from 2 digits to 3 that fooled me.
Everything works nicely ;-)
i.e. 95 was the old no. 104 was the new..(and yes I had deleted the builds in between)